# Shortest path between two vertices of a hyper-rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How can I efficiently find the shortest path between two vertices in a hyper-rectangle?

By 'efficiently', I certainly mean 'without prior enumeration of the vertices', which is obviously O(2^dim).

Comment: Fix all coordinates which are the same for both vertices, and change the rest one by one.

Comment: I can see that would work for a hypercube, but AFAICS simply 'changing one by one' is describing a nondeterministic algorithm that would not be efficient. Presumably stronger constraints need to be incorporated to make an efficient choice of which coordinates to change.

Comment: Don't all such paths have the same length?

Comment: You're saying that 'all paths such that the Hamming distance between successive vertices is one' have the same length? I think that's true in a hypercube, but not AFAICS in a hyperrectangle.

Comment: We are traversing the same edges, probably in different order. How can the total length not be the same?

Comment: What about the 'Travelling Salesman', which yields different distances over permutations of visitation order?

Comment: That's on an arbitrary graph, not a hyper-rectangle.

Comment: Agreed. Still not clear to me that total length is invariant to visitation-order on a hyper-rectangle, but perhaps that's my lack of geometric insight...